# How can I override the default twig {{ variable }} output?

Tags: twig

I'm trying to output my twig templates with markup to indicate whats in the template. For instance, instead of `{{ name }}` becoming `value` in the output, I want it to become:

```
<div class="twig-variable">name</div>
```

Note: I don't want to have to edit the twig template.

Answer (score 0):

Pass this variable to twig on rendering
`$twig->render('/path/to/template', array('var1'=>'val1', 'var2'=>'val2'));`
template
`<div class="twig-variable">{{ var1 }}</div><div class="twig-variable">{{ var2 }}</div>`
output
`<div class="twig-variable">val1</div><div class="twig-variable">val2</div>`

Also you can define default value of variable in template, that is used when variable was not passed to twig on rendering
`{{ var1|default('default val1') }}`

Comment: I don't want the value to be output, nor do I want to have to modify the twig template.